# How can I test an internet connection during a certain period of time?

Tags: testing, networking, qos

I would like to test the internet connection of some place. Therefore I want to write my own script which is triggered every some random minutes to do some stuff.

I was thinking about:

- Getting the latency until I ping some big site.
- Downloading a big file from somewhere. (Bandwitdh)

But I think this is not reliable as probably the file that I try to get is cached in some provider' server.

Are there more checks necessary to measure the quality of the internet connection (Availability, Latency and Bandwith)?

How can I avoid having my requests cached?